# How to remove white pixels that are not connected to a loop in binary image

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-morphology, image-thresholding

I have a [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Od8Fi.jpg) which I have binarized and the problem is I want to remove the white spots in that image which are not connected in a loop i.e. small white dots. The reason is I want to take a measurement of that section like shown [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUPFH.png)

I have tried some OpenCV morphology functions like erode, open, close but the results are not what I require. I have also tried using canny edge but some diagonal lines which I want for some processing are also gone. [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfTlc.png) 
is the result of both thresh(left) and canny(right)

I have read that pruning is a process in which we remove pixels which are not connected but I don't know how it works? Is there a function in Opencv for that?

```
th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray_img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
th3=~th3
th3 = cv2.dilate(th3, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(3,3)))
th3 = cv2.erode(th3, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(5,5)))
edged = cv2.Canny(gray_img,lower,upper)
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer explains how to measure the diameter of the drill bit:

The first step is to read the image as 2 channel (grayscale) and find the edges using a Canny filter:

```
img = cv2.imread('/home/stephen/Desktop/drill.jpg',0)
canny = cv2.Canny(img, 100, 100)
```

[image: canny]

The edges of the drill using `np.argmax()`:

```
diameters = []
# Iterate through each column in the image
for row in range(img.shape[1]-1):
    img_row = img[:, row:row+1]
    start = np.argmax(img_row)
    end = np.argmax(np.flip(img_row))
    diameters.append(end+start)
    a = row, 0
    b = row, start
    c = row, img.shape[1]
    d = row, img.shape[0] - end
    cv2.line(img, a, b, 123, 1)
    cv2.line(img, c, d, 123, 1)
```

[image: outline]

The diameter of the drill in each column is plotted here:

[image: diameters]

All of this assumes that you have an aligned image. I used [this code](https://gist.github.com/smeschke/aa989df78551a9050a78e0d7a8c50495) to align the image.

Comment: That could help me for extracting some features from thread part but I couldn't understand the graph. What is x-axis and what is y-axis, what are the peaks and valleys. If you are kind enough to explain that, and can I  find some thread features of drill bit with this algorithm. Consider me a noob

Comment: Please review my edits. I superimposed the drill bit in the graph image.

Comment: Sir I am not able to align my image like yours could you please tell me the steps you used in that code link?